# Why file name should not be started with hyphen or underline?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, filenames, cpanel

And also in the following document, He said: " Avoid using underscores in a filename "

http://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/digital/writing/characters-avoid/

Why?

Can i use underscores or start with hyphen or underline in this format (instead of star) : *.txt

Answer (score 4):

You can use special characters in filenames: [link (linux)](http://linuxg.net/the-7-main-rules-for-naming-files-and-folders-in-linux-and-unix/)

- Files that start with `_` may be ignored by some programs. [link](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/)
- Web: Underscores in files vs underlined html links
- `-` are also used as switches to command line programs, will be a bit confusing to have hyphens in you filenames as well as command switches. i.e. `> java -version`
- Troublesome to escape the dash character in *nix i.e. `$ cat ./-file` [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189251/how-to-read-dash-files)
- Magic of `-` in command line parameters [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045479/whats-the-magic-of-a-dash-in-command-line-parameters)

Comment: `-` and `--` are used as switches in almost all programs in Linux, not only some

Comment: in your opinion, can i use something like _test.txt or -test.txt in my Cpanel in my linux hosting? tnx :(

Comment: @MahdiJazini I've no experience with Cpanel, but why do you need to use such a filename? Is it to surface it to the top of a list?

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc well, compared to cmd line params in Windows

Comment: @SimplyInk Because, I'm creating a text base database instead of MySQL to decrease costs of my hosting to support more online users with cheap prices. i want to store usernames in a hidden area like this format *.txt. the * can be letter or number or _ or - or dot. I want users to be able to make usernames with - and _ Now I have found a way to store them. i'll encode them to hexadecimal or something like this. anyway tnx for your time :) God bless you all :)

Comment: @MahdiJazini interesting use case, i wonder how well it scales with more users

Comment: @SimplyInk well this question is specifically tagged with Linux and is not related to Windows whatsoever. In Windows the switch is `/`. `-` is generally only used in programs ported from Linux

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc my bad, missed the *nix tag.